# Where to place jstatd.all.policy

Tags: java, linux, jstat

I'd like to grant permissions to my jstatd on linux
The corresponding manual reads:

> To use this policy, copy the text into a file called jstatd.all.policy
>   and run the jstatd server as follows:
>
> jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy

But where on linux should I place this jstatd.all.policy file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i remember you have to create the file in the same location as `jstatd` (...jdk/bin/) and it should work.

Update:
From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html):

> The user policy file is by default located at
>
> `user.home/.java.policy` (Solaris/Linux)
>
> `user.home\.java.policy` (Windows)
>
> Note: `user.home` refers to the value of the system property
>   named `"user.home"`, which specifies the user's home directory.

Comment: Any ideas about alternative locations? ${JAVA_HOME/bin} is on a read-only filesystem which I don't control here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also give a full path to the policy that would be used such as:

```
jstatd -p 1099 -J-Xrs -J-Djava.security.policy=C:\jstatd\tools.policy
```

This is helpful if you are on a shared machine and want a central place to add policies.